# Preview action items in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, 3dtouch

How do i assign preview action items in swift 3? The function doesn't seem to be there and the property is get only

I've hit the same issue when i try to input the supportedinterfaceorientations

Is there something that I've missed?

I've tried this on Xcode 8.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how you should be accessing it henceforth

```
override var previewActionItems: [UIPreviewActionItem] {
    return previewActionItems
}
```

Same goes for supportedinterfaceorientations as well